# Samples in a PCA form lines, what are the reasons?

Tags: pca

I have come across some PCA plots in which the samples are forming "lines", such as this one:

[image: Herráez et al 2009]

Or this one:

[image: http://www.ryantimpe.com/post/peabody-insta1/]

What kind of data can generate such PCA plots? Are there anything wrong with these PCA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the PCA was done correctly, in the end it is a simple linear transformation, projecting the data into a lower-dimensional space such that the most variance is preserved. Since the transformation is linear, it will not straighten or bend any lines you might have in the data, unless the line curves along one of the directions that is discarded by the projection. Hence, if the data forms lines after the transformation, it implies that it formed a line in the original space or that it curved on a plane, which gets projected down to a line.
So the PCAs you show look fine to me.

Regarding the question what data can generate such lines: lines in feature space imply a strong [linear correlation](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Correlation) of these features, i.e. it is reasonable to assume that there is a function $x_2 = m x_1 + b$ that relates the features $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

In general (or common cases) you would find those lines when applying PCA, which are the result of finding those Principal Components Analysis, meaning the directions of maximum variance of your original datatset, i.e., the components which give you more information out of your data.
As explained with examples in scikit-learn docu: PCA finds orthogonal directions in the raw feature space that correspond to directions accounting for maximum variance.